# What to do when voting fails (upvoted incorrect answer)

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

A few days ago I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515265/sql-server-case-then-statement-error) which in a short time got several incorrect answers that for some reason got upvotes, presumably because they seemed to fix the most obvious and apparent problem while missing that the code in the question had another more serious error that the correct and accepted answer addressed.

Two of the three incorrect answers were subsequently deleted, but [one incorrect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29515404/1175077) remains with a vote count standing at +4/-3 for a total of +1 (at this time).

This bothers me, because having an incorrect answer upvoted at all is bad in my opinion, and in this case the answerer should be aware that it is incorrect as it's been pointed out by several people (me included), and the answer has been revised several times - although never to a working state.

In my opinion the answer should either be fixed, or deleted, but I can't see any incentive for the poster to actually do this. Removing the answer would cost the answerer 34 rep (which is more than 30% of his total), which would be a pretty strong incentive not to do so even though gaining three down votes should be a strong signal to correct or remove.

Maybe I shouldn't care that one incorrect answer (of many on SO I'm sure) has a positive score, or that it has led to a 34 point rep gain, but it does bother me (the rep gain not as much as having an incorrect answer showing as useful though).

What, if anything at all, should I do about this?

Just to clarify: I have no personal stake in this, I didn't answer the question.

Comment: *"they seemed to fix the most obvious and apparent problem"* - so are they partial answers, rather than completely incorrect?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I guess so. Although they addressed a minor syntax error inside a major one. They in no way solved the underlying problem.

Comment: I'd downvote it and move on. By bringing it up on meta, it will get more downvotes now anyway.

Comment: I suggest you never look at [tag:c++] questions dealing with raw pointers or arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the answer is found to be useful by someone, they *should* up-vote it. If you don't like an answer, downvote it. Simple really.

Not every answer is going to be perfect, if that was the model we wanted, we would only allow one answer to exist per question. The general flow you would see is that a few people answer a question focusing on different aspects, then realising they missed details, 'borrow' from each other.

Eventually a good solid answer will bubble up that provides both the 'quick fix' that the user wanted, but also the solid advice on how to generally do things better.

If it really bothers you that the answer is not addressing all you feel it should, and no other answer is, then write your own answer. I've even done it on questions where the answer is in the comment but no one has bothered to formally 'answer' it.

You can also leave comments. Again, something I'd often do. Explain that whilst this addresses the obvious first problem that ~this~ would be much better way of dealing with things.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was that the upvotes most likely came from people that lacked the knowledge necessary to properly judge the validity of the answer - why would someone otherwise upvote something that doesn't solve the problem? Of course not all answers will be perfect - I know many of mine are not - but shouldn't the bar at least be at the "it works" level? Anyway, just food for thought. thanks for your input.