# How to make a (in my opinion) correct edit when it is rejected by review?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I'd like some advice regarding an edit which I would like to see happen but which has been rejected by community review.

I've tried to edit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6783054) answer. ( *How long to brute force a salted SHA-512 hash? (salt provided)* )

The answer contains false information, and I believe it should be edited to correct this. But I've made two attempts which have failed: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20170415) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20177283). The reasons given were along the lines of "belongs in a comment" or "changes the author's intent". Indeed, the edits may very well change the author's intent, although I took great pains to attempt to preserve that intent, including a perhaps awkward segue in the first edit.

What should I do to edit it? Or perhaps, while I don't believe false information should persist in an answer, is it not appropriate to edit it as described?

Comment: Leave a comment, and move on.

Comment: That answer is **ridiculously wrong**, I don't understand why it had so many upvotes. Is there any way to delete that answer ?

Comment: @liliscent I know right?

Comment: [Relevant](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: See also [What to do when voting fails (upvoted incorrect answer)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289875), [How to handle historical, highly upvoted but completely incorrect answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255198), [Is commenting on incorrect answer the proper way to point out it's wrong?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254929), [Are old, upvoted answers harder to get removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277042)...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the answer is utter nonsense, and it's distressing to see it's attracted >100 upvotes, an edit was not a legitimate remedy for that and the rejections were correct. An edit that "corrected" this answer would need to completely delete at least the entire first half of it, if not more, and replace it with a completely new answer, and that's not a thing we do. Third-party edits are meant to preserve the author's intent, and if the core thesis of an answer is fundamentally wrong, that means it should *stay* wrong unless the author themselves decides to edit.

The potential remedies available are to downvote, comment, upvote existing comments, answer, upvote existing competing answers, attempt to persuade the author (on-site or off-site) that his answer is embarrassingly wrong and he should self-flag for deletion, or post a Meta post arguing that this is such an egregiously wrong answer on a security topic that it deserves treating as a special case and nuking by the mods. (I'm not sure I would agree if you took the final approach - *yes*, it's terribly wrong, but it's not clear to me that the wrongness will lead to any insecure practices being used in real life. But Meta is here for you to make the case if you wish.)

But that (awful, wrong in almost every detail) accepted answer is still what 121 people upvoted. It would not be right to completely swap out the content of the answer from under their feet and make it say something almost entire unrelated, and that's what it would take to turn it into a decent answer.